# Slideout.js menu isnt smooth

Tags: javascript, css, menu, sidebar

I have been trying to get slideout.js to work properly for my site.

The issue is that when the menu is opened, the text appears before the fully opens and when the menu is closed, the text disappears after the menu is closed.

I have looked at the CSS and made sure that there are backgrounds to the menu and heights are correctly set.

Demo (view as mobile) - http://stefan.admark.co.uk/gates/index.php

JS:

```
      window.onload = function() {
        var slideout = new Slideout({
          'panel': document.getElementById('main'),
          'menu': document.getElementById('menu'),
          'side': 'right',
          'padding': 256,
  'tolerance': 70
        });

        document.querySelector('.js-slideout-toggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
          slideout.toggle();
        });

      };
```

CSS:

```
.slideout-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 256px;
  /* min-height: 100vh; */
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  z-index: 999;
  display: none;
  padding-left:20px;
}

.slideout-menu-left {
  left: 0;
}

.slideout-menu-right {
  right: 0;
}

.slideout-panel {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  will-change: transform;
  background-color: #ffffff; /* A background-color is required */
  min-height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
-moz-box-shadow: 6px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
box-shadow: 6px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.slideout-open,
.slideout-open body,
.slideout-open .slideout-panel {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slideout-open .slideout-menu {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .slideout-panel {
    /* margin-left: 256px; */
  }

  .slideout-menu {
    display: none;
  }

}

.panel:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.panel-open:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code for the html and .js causing the issue?

Comment: The CSS and JS has been posted.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `<nav>` element on your page doesn't have any transition CSS on it.

For instance, your `<main>` element has the following transition applied to it:

```
transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease 0s; transform: translateX(-256px)
```

Whatever javascript you have triggering the transition for your `<main>` element, if applied to `<nav>` should cause the text and everything inside `<nav>` to transition properly as well.

Comment: I will try this, but if you look at the demo site for slideout.js it does not have this and it is smooth. https://slideout.js.org/

Comment: I took the Full Example code from the [slideout.js docs](https://github.com/mango/slideout#full-example) and put it in a [codesandbox.io demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/llwyvq3937) and the "Menu" text still doesn't transition properly.